# PHP stops serving requests after awhile and returns errors 502 - 504

Tags: php, laravel, apache, amazon-ec2

I currently have a Amazon EC2 instance (t3.small) running Apache and PHP 7.2 which serves a Laravel application.

After running for awhile, php will stop responding to requests (apache still receives them and forwards them to php, verified this using apachetop to see incoming requests). In Apache, there will errors such as follows and returns errors 502-504 and takes very long to recover until restarted. Here are some logs which might help find the issue.

```
[Wed Jan 20 05:25:57.287493 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2517:tid 140104425260800] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 172.31.40.9:6946] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : , referer: https://mysite
[Wed Jan 20 05:25:59.608161 2021] [suexec:notice] [pid 3853:tid 139828464464448] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Jan 20 05:25:59.627458 2021] [so:warn] [pid 3853:tid 139828464464448] AH01574: module headers_module is already loaded, skipping
[Wed Jan 20 05:25:59.627877 2021] [so:warn] [pid 3853:tid 139828464464448] AH01574: module cgid_module is already loaded, skipping
[Wed Jan 20 05:25:59.633440 2021] [mpm_event:warn] [pid 3853:tid 139828464464448] AH00514: MaxRequestWorkers of 404 is not an integer multiple of ThreadsPerChild of 25, decreasing to nearest multiple 400
[Wed Jan 20 05:25:59.636514 2021] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3853:tid 139828464464448] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Jan 20 05:25:59.648040 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3853:tid 139828464464448] AH00489: Apache/2.4.46 () OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 20 05:25:59.648081 2021] [core:notice] [pid 3853:tid 139828464464448] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Jan 20 05:28:48.232549 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 3897:tid 139827752199936] (111)Connection refused: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[Wed Jan 20 05:28:48.232596 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 3897:tid 139827752199936] [client 172.31.40.9:8904] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS, referer: https://mysite

[Wed Jan 20 05:28:48.243356 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 4144:tid 139827743807232] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[Wed Jan 20 05:28:48.243356 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 4144:tid 139826972038912] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed

[Wed Jan 20 06:46:28.744679 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 6584:tid 139720269829888] [client 172.31.40.9:14942] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header, referer: https://mysite
[Wed Jan 20 06:46:28.744687 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 6584:tid 139720269829888] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 172.31.40.9:14942] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : , referer: https://mysite
[Wed Jan 20 06:46:31.657254 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6559:tid 139720919990848] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Jan 20 06:46:32.729979 2021] [suexec:notice] [pid 6937:tid 140554580320832] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

But, by having a cron job that runs `php artisan schedule:run` every minute, this behavior of not 'serving any request' will not occur.

So, I'm wondering if it is a configuration issue or is it something else?

Comment: Look like your php-fpm service stops working for some reason, did you check php-fpm logs ?

Comment: @JulienB. by checking the status of the php-fpm status via `serivce php-fpm status` it will show that it is up